# excel saving with VBA issues and ways around it

Tags: vba, excel, save

I have a relatively involved sub that transfers a bunch of data around within a workbook in excel and does a handful of other things, then saves the file at the end of the sub using `activeWorkbook.save`

however for reasons unknown to me, when the file has been open for a long time and I save it gives me a message saying the file has been edited by another user and prompts me to either notify the other user and not save or overwrite any changes made by the other user. Is there a way to code the sub to make it overwrite no matter what, so that if that dialog box comes up, it doesn't prevent the sub from running?

Also, there is no one else editing the file so i don't know why its giving me the message in the first place, i just want it to bypass that if it happens to come up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: `If ThisWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then ThisWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess`?

Comment: where would I put that code? outside of a sub?

Comment: In the `Workbook_Open` event inside `ThisWorkbook`, before any editing is done.  You will also need to handle the situation where that fails and you cannot get the exclusive access so it's dealt with gracefully

Comment: @Dave I don't think that it should be in the `Workbook_Open` event. Otherwise then the file wouldn't / shouldn't be in [Shared Mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61) anyway. But apparently (every now and then) multiple users have to work on it. So, the *exclusive* mode should be only enforced when absolutely need. The OP will have to specify the requirements in order for us to suggest how this should be initiated. If the file never needs to be in shared mode then its easy: remove the share, save the file. Done.

Comment: @Ralph, you're right, I'm thinking of some of the spreadsheets I administer here where that code is in the `Workbook_Open` event, but also after the user id has been retrieved; the code is conditional upon which user is accessing the file; for example when I open the file, it gives me the exclusive access since I'll need it for whatever changes I'm making to its design, but not for other users who just process work through it

Comment: @Dave Sounds like a feasible solution. I guess you make use of `environ("UserDomain") & "\" & environ("UserName")` to determine the users (using Windows Authentication / [SSPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380493(v=vs.85).aspx))? I hope you are aware that this provides no security and anybody with access to the file could easily change this within the VBA of the file. Anyway, I guess we both can tell from this interesting little discourse that the post needs more specifics in order for us to provide a recommendation.

Comment: @Ralph sorry, what other specifics can i add to help the situation? I just want the VBA to overwrite the previous save regardless of if it has been edited by someone else

Comment: @Vbasic4now Based on your recent edit it seems that the file shouldn't be in Shared Mode at all. So, if you go in the Excel menu to `Review` ► `Changes` ► `Share Workbook` and remove the tag next to `Allow changes by more than one user...` on the Editing tab then you should be done. Just save it (once you removed the CheckBox). If other users are re-enabling this CheckBox then you might want to put the above code into the `Workbook_Open` event anyway (cause someone re-enables it while you want it disabled). Just note that a `Save` is required each time you change that CheckBox.

Comment: @Ralph that tag is already unchecked. thats why im confused as to why it says the file has been edited by another user. It only gives me that message after being open for a long time. like 5 or 6 hours

Comment: @Ralph I am indeed aware of the security implications, but the spreadsheets in question live on an internal Sharepoint that requires specific access, and the actual vb code modules inside are protected too.  As an aside, my code doesn't rely on `Environ`, rather it picks up the logged in user id from a `Wscript.Network` call

Comment: @Vbasic4now Then this shared access to your Excel file is not provided by Excel itself but by something else (outside of Excel). Does the file reside on a SharePoint server (or any other kind of server with sharing / tracking features)? If that's the case then you can probably get exclusive access with the following: `If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(ThisWorkbook.FullName) = True Then Workbooks.CheckOut ThisWorkbook.FullName`.

Comment: @Ralph I am on a server, but I am not trying to get exclusive access to the file, I just want it to save over any changes that have been made, "force save" if you will

Comment: Have you tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: @Ralph wouldn't that just keep the alert from showing but still not save the file?

Comment: No. Just make sure to set `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` right after the save again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we have finally found a solution for this problem:

```
ThisWorkbook.Saved = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.FullName, FileFormat:=52
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then MsgBox "Saving the file failed." & Chr(10) & "Please try again later..."
```

The `.Saved` property of a workbook is readable and writable. So, the first line makes sure that this file is marked as "not saved". This is important because alters are disabled and we would not know if the file has been really saved (without this property).

Once the file has been attempted to save (here as `.xlsm`, you might want / have to change that) the `.Saved` property is read to ensure that the save actually worked.